# How to use the WebP image format in DotNetNuke?

Tags: performance, webp, dnn9

I am trying to add the following code to my DotNetNuke website to improve site performance, but it seems like .**WebP** format images do not render for some reason, It will show the broken Image icon. I doubled checked the image paths and everything is correct. I had to download a plugin for Photoshop CC so that I can export images to .WebP.

Is there a web.config setting I have to configure?

```
<picture>
<source srcset="img/awesomeWebPImage.webp" type="image/webp">
<source srcset="img/creakyOldJPEG.jpg" type="image/jpeg"> 
<img src="img/creakyOldJPEG.jpg" alt="Alt Text!">
</picture>
```

Comment: Try using a different browser maybe.

Answer (score 1):

This is more a problem of your IIS configuration than related to DNN. You have to add a corresponding MIME type, either in IIS manager or manually in the web.config like

```
<system.webServer>
   <staticContent>
      ...
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".webp" mimeType="image/webp" />
      ...
```